# MongoDb 3.2 : Updating records

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a requirement that it need to update all embedded documents with same attribute.

```
e.g.  `Person  oneToMany  Addresses`
```

here Addresses is embedded document and i want to write a query which will give result that if, for embedded document,i write `city="New York"` my all embedded documents should be updated as `city="New York"`.

EDIT:

**I have given parent Document 'id' in embeded document**

Below is method :

```
public Boolean updateAddressIsolataed(AddressModel addressModel) {
    final Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria( 
            Criteria.where("$isolated").is(1).and(PersonEntity.Address)
            .elemMatch(Criteria.where("parentId").is(addressModel.getParentId())));

    System.out.println("query:" + query.toString());
    final Update update = new Update();
    update.set(PersonEntity.Address + ".$." + "city", addressModel.getCity());
    WriteResult wr = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, PersonEntity);
    return wr.isUpdateOfExisting();
```

If need any more explanation please ask me.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2 :**

*sample document:*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571da15563500213286936bf"),
    "_class" : "com.sample.entities.PersonEntity",
    "name" : "Asin",
    "age" : "22",
    "address" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5735acc5b29cadaf65a7f822"),
                    "parentId" : "571da15563500213286936bf",
                    "city" : "New York",
                    "state" : "QWERTY",
                    "zipcode" : 500

            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5735acc5b29cadaf65a7f822"),
                    "parentId" : "571da15563500213286936bf",
                    "city" : "Mumbai",
                    "state" : "Maharashtra",
                    "zipcode" : 500

            }
    ]
```

}

Comment: Have you tried doing something for yourself first?

Comment: yes, I have tried but it gives me only one record to update. I checked it in their documentation also but didnt find anything which will match this

Comment: Please, update your question with the query you've created in order to show us your efforts.

Comment: Updated with code, this code update only first matched record not all

Comment: At least, someone tell me how to write query(command line) for it. I will make code on my own.

Comment: @user3245368 can you please provide sample document

Comment: Sample Document Added. @Reminder , according to document ,              if I query city = 'Delhi'     then   it    should update  both embeded documents'  city = 'Delhi'.  Hence I have inserted parentId in embeded Document.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for positional $ operator says, you only get the first match, and this is currently how things work by design.

***It is not possible till date to update all matched sub-documents.***

For more info :

You can have look at [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243)